# $scope.$on fired 3 times

Tags: angularjs, controllers

I have 2 different angular controllers and one of it having broadcast like this

```
$timeout(function() {
    if($scope.modal){
      $rootScope.$broadcast(DATAINPUT_EVENT.REFRESH_COMPLETED_DATA_LIST,id);
      $scope.modal.hide();
      $scope.modal.remove();
    }
}, 3000);
```

And in another controller I am catching broadcast.

```
$scope.$on(DATAINPUT_EVENT.REFRESH_COMPLETED_DATA_LIST,function(event,id){
    // some action
});
```

Problem is **$scope.$on** function getting called 3 times. I have referred

- [AngularJs broadcast repeating execution too many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553598/angularjs-broadcast-repeating-execution-too-many-times) and
- [Angular - broadcast , $on called multiple times in directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26775628/angular-broadcast-on-called-multiple-times-in-directive)

but could not get solution using them. Please help me out...!!

Comment: What is the context of that `$timeout` call? What causes it to execute?

Comment: Can you post your HTML how you are loading your different controllers ! If you have initiated same controller more than once then this issue is possible.

Comment: Right.... @Angular_10 its happening because of multiple controllers are loaded at some point. I am still looking how this happening...

Comment: Thats why gimme your code let me find that out !

Comment: Thanks @Angular_10 I have found  it  finally.... I have header where same controller was used in ng-controller that's why it was registering $scope.$on event multiple times. Issue has been resolved  for me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix issue for a moment, I did something like follows,

```
if(!$rootScope.$$listenerCount[DATAINPUT_EVENT.REFRESH_COMPLETED_DATA_LIST]){
    $scope.$on(DATAINPUT_EVENT.REFRESH_COMPLETED_DATA_LIST,function(event,id){
         // some action
    });
}
```

But very soon I found I have initialized my controller multiple times and I have taken corrective actions to remove the multiple declarations of controller.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty hack: use a boolean flag

```
var once = true;
$timeout(function() {
   if($scope.modal){          
      $rootScope.$broadcast(DATAINPUT_EVENT.REFRESH_COMPLETED_DATA_LIST, {id: id, once: once});
      $scope.modal.hide();
      $scope.modal.remove();
      once = false;
   }
}, 3000);
```

and in your listener:

```
$scope.$on(DATAINPUT_EVENT.REFRESH_COMPLETED_DATA_LIST,function(event,args){
   if(args.once)
      // some action, only the first time
});
```

Bear in mind this is (dirty, but still) solution only if you can't find why your broadcast it's called 3 times every event.

Comment: Thanks @Luxor, this was only happened for that event only so and it was because of controllers I used in my header template. Now its all fine. Problem has been solved now.