# Angularjs $broadcast once, $on twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, event-listener, angular-broadcast

It sends $broadcast once from the rootScope, but the listener ($on) gets called twice.

The listener is in a controller and it uses `$rootScope.$on` instead of `$scope.$on`. Has someone had this problem?

**edit**

rootScope:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('menuActivateAction' + item.event_name_postfix, item.event_args);
```

other Controller:

```
$rootScope.$on('menuActivateActionPublish', function(event) {});
```

Comment: you should provide your code

Comment: Maybe you have two controllers?

Comment: Probably you have to remove the listener when the controller is destroyed. I'd even register the listener in the `.run` phase and not in the controller - to avoid auch problems the controller should only register listener on is own scope

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs broadcast repeating execution too many times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553598/angularjs-broadcast-repeating-execution-too-many-times)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since you register your $on listener on $rootScope, it doesn't get destroyed with the controller and next time you init the controller it gets created again.

You should create your listener on controller scope

```
$scope.$on('menuActivateActionPublish', function(event) {});
```

Comment: Hey in my case on listen called incrementally.

Comment: @UmairKhanzada sorry I dont understand that comment

Comment: listen `$rootScope.$broadcast('xyz');` event when user login and when user logout and  login again it'll be listen incrementally. listen function `$rootScope.$on('xyz', function(){ console.log('running')});`

Comment: It depends on where do you have `$broadcast` and `$on` . In your case, you should have `$broadcast()` in function that handles login - wherever you determine that user is logged in, and `$on()` only in single place. For example `app.run()`. That is if you want to use `$rootScope`. If you want to use it in controllers or other "modules"  then use `$scope.$on()` and as many times you want, because it gets destroyed

Answer (score 10):

Be careful you avoid two instances of the controller means two event listeners, which means the method gets executed twice !! ( example: using twice 'ng-controller' )

Answer (score 5):

To complement que1326 answer, as an example, if you are using ui-router and have something like

```
.state('app.yourpage', {
            url:'yourPage',
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl : 'views/yourPage.html',
                    controller  : 'YourController'
                }
            }
        })
```

and in yourPage.html you have a `ng-controller="YourController as Ctrl"`, then you are creating 2 instances of the controller: 1 instance is created by the state configuration and another one in your html.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could get to work was to create the listener inside the $viewContentLoaded event:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
  //Put your listener(s) in here
  $scope.$on('menuActivateActionPublish', function(event) {});
});
```